# Error splitting rows based on column regex

Tags: r, data.table

I'm getting a strange error splitting rows of a data.table based on the value of one of the columns. If I create the following data.table:

```
example <- data.table(dt=c("2016-08-18 16:04:37.0", "2016-08-11 18:01:44.0", "2016-08-11 18:01:44.0"),
                                   latitude = c(58.64347, 59.73744, 59.73744), 
                                   countrycode = c("SE", "SE", "SE"), 
                                   city = c("Mariestad", "Norrtälje", "Norrtälje"), 
                                   street = c("E20", "E18", "E18"), 
                                   streetnr = c(NA, NA, NA), 
                                   postalcode = c(54274, 76192, 76192))
```

And I try to split the first two rows based on the value of the column `street` (I'm trying to find patterns like E18/E20/E21), I can execute this:

```
example[1:2, strsplit(street, "/", fixed = T),by = "countrycode,city,streetnr,postalcode"]
```

And everything is fine, it doesn't split the rows because it doesn't find the "/".

```
   countrycode      city streetnr postalcode  V1
1:          SE Mariestad       NA      54274 E20
2:          SE Norrtälje       NA      76192 E18
```

But if I try to split the last row:

```
example[2:3, strsplit(street, "/", fixed = T), by = "countrycode,city,streetnr,postalcode"]
```

I get this:

```
   countrycode      city streetnr postalcode  V1  V2
1:          SE Norrtälje       NA      76192 E18 E18
```

As you can see, It creates two new columns (V1 and V2) with the same value ("E18"), whereas in the previous command, it just created one new column (V1). If I try to split just the first row (with a streetcode of "E20" instead of "E18"), it works without any issue:

```
example[1:1, strsplit(street, "/", fixed = T), by = "countrycode,city,streetnr,postalcode"]

   countrycode      city streetnr postalcode  V1
1:          SE Mariestad       NA      54274 E20
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? Could be related to the character codification or something like that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really clear to me what you'd like to see here. `strsplit` returns a list with a length equal to the number of elements in the vector you give it. In the 1:2 case, you've got two length-one lists (one in each `by` group) -- these are stacked on top of each other. In the second case, you have one length-two list -- these are put into separate columns...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strsplit` returns a list with length equal to your input vector. When `DT[, j, by]` sees a list in `j`, it interprets it as a list of columns. If you want everything in a single column, you can unlist:

```
example[, 
  .(ssplit = unlist(strsplit(street, "/", fixed = TRUE)))
, by = "countrycode,city,streetnr,postalcode"]
```

Doing `by=` here is very inefficient and requires enumerating all the col names. Possibly better:

```
s = strsplit(example$street, "/", fixed=TRUE)
example[rep(1:.N, lengths(s)), c(.SD, .(ssplit = unlist(s)))]


                      dt latitude countrycode      city street streetnr postalcode ssplit
1: 2016-08-18 16:04:37.0 58.64347          SE Mariestad    E20       NA      54274    E20
2: 2016-08-11 18:01:44.0 59.73744          SE Norrtälje    E18       NA      76192    E18
3: 2016-08-11 18:01:44.0 59.73744          SE Norrtälje    E18       NA      76192    E18
```

Comment: Thank you very much